# Are there any benchmarking programs?

Tags: benchmarking

Is there a way to benchmark the performance of my Raspberry Pi?

I'd be looking at Upload/Download speeds, reads, writes, and general processing stuff.

Comment: You will find benchmark tools for specific actions, such as up/download speed, but not one that will cover all bases. Perhaps specify the areas that you want to test?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best benchmark would be, but I'm looking for an empirical way to measure video performance and CPU performance, comparing my results to what I was able to previously achieve in a different distro or in a different configuration.

Comment: @Zoot: Have any luck with this? - am also looking for something - mainly to benchmark CPU for the moment.

Comment: iperf is a great program! for testing the network. Others http://elinux.org/RPi_Performance.

Comment: @Haskeller Please make your comment as an answer so I can treat it like one. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1364/894) is directly related and linked to other answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) is an excellent program for measuring maximum bandwidth between networks.

```
#Sever listening on TCP port 1337
ip route
iperf -s -p 1337
#Sever listening on UDP port 1337
iperf -s -u -p 1337
#Client connecting to server IP(TCP)
iperf -c <IP_ADDR> -p 1337 -t <TIME> -i <PING_TIME> -f m -d
#Client connecting to server IP(UDP)
iperf -c <IP_ADDR> -u -p 1337 -t <TIME> -i <PING_TIME> -f m -d
```

From the [elinux wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_Performance)

USB Bus(write to an external storage device)

```
dd if=/mnt/drivehere/test of=/dev/null bs=32M count=10 iflag=direct
```

SD card read and write

```
# write
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/test.tmp bs=500K count=1024 
# read
dd if=~/test.tmp of=/dev/null bs=500K count=1024
```

CPU linpack

```
wget http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/linpackc.new
mv linpackc.new linpack.c
cc -O3 -o linpack linpack.c -lm
```

GPU benchmarking is quite hard since OpenCl isn't supported. A rough benchmark would be `ioquake3` and `glxgears` for comparing the frame rate.You could also use [OpenGl:ES](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGLNFIWZHbQ) as [ppumkin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/894/ppumkin) noted.

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) can also help measure performance by relating it to the previous configurations you had. [How to setup munin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/how-do-i-set-up-munin)

Comment: [OpenGl:ES Benchmarking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGLNFIWZHbQ&feature=watch_response) - I wish I could embed video answers. don't you?