# How do I set up munin?

Tags: monitoring

How do you set up a [munin-node](http://munin-monitoring.org/) on the Raspberry Pi?

> Munin is a networked resource monitoring tool that can help analyze
>   resource trends and "what just happened to kill our performance?"
>   problems. It is designed to be very plug and play. A default
>   installation provides a lot of graphs with almost no work.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For Raspbian, this has got me started so far:

Raspberry Pi is on `192.168.1.22`
Munin Server is on `192.168.1.8`

On the RPi as root

```
# apt-get install munin-node
# munin-node-configure --suggest --shell
```

Edit /etc/munin/munin-node.conf. Under this line

```
allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
```

Add an entry for the munin server

```
allow ^192.168.1.8$
```

Now, you need to tell the server to look for this node, on the server edit /etc/munin/munin.conf. Add an entry for the RPi

```
[RPi.localdomain]
    address 192.168.1.22
    use_node_name yes
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to monitor a few simple things, check out [muninlite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/muninlite/). It's a fairly simple shell script which is meant to be run from inetd/xinetd. Since it's so small and only uses shell utilities, it's very easy to add your own plugins, e.g. if you want to monitor sensors connected to the GPIO pins.