# CPU Performance Graph

Tags: raspbian, cpu, monitoring

Is it possible to get a larger view of the CPU graph shown in the bottom right of my Raspbian desktop?

Just to show the graph I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: There are a number of flashier, more configurable monitors around if you want -- look into `gkrellm` or `conky`.

Answer (score 2):

did you look into using the system recently displayed on the RaspberryPi.org blog? https://github.com/davidsblog/rCPU

Comment: Isn't this besides the point?  The question is about getting a view of CPU usage *locally* and you are posting links about a *remote* monitor?

Comment: I must admit I just assumed it would be possible to open a browser on the Pi, but you're right, that might add such a processor overhead as to render the graphs useless. (I don't know how little processing gkreidl's minimal kiosk browser takes, for instance)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible and if you have a browser open anyway it is probably pretty efficient, in fact -- more so than running a dedicated GUI...maybe. But then just `top` or some other terminal app will be more efficient again...I was pointing this out because if you want a GUI CPU (+RAM, etc) monitor, there are piles of them around (see Steve's answer and my comment on the Q); you don't have to resort to something web based -- I think the appeal there would be more if you are running headless.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make the panel applet larger, but there are several alternatives that will do what you want. Some simple methods to get the same info from the terminal include:

1. [tload](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tload.htm) - this will output the standard usage for 1, 5, and 15 minute intervals, and uses ascii art to graph it,
2. [top](http://www.unixtutorial.org/commands/top/) and [htop](http://blog.tafkas.net/2013/07/09/using-htop-to-monitor-system-srocesses-on-the-raspberry-pi/) will do the same (though top does not have the ascii art).

If you want something graphical you have several options than span a large range of complexity and resource requirements:

1. [munin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1358/56),
2. [cacti](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/105702-raspberrypi-how-to-install-cacti),
3. [nagios](http://citycorpse.com/install-nagios-on-pi/),
4. [Dstat + GNUPlot](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/create-a-graph-of-your-systems-performance)
5. [RPI-Monitor](https://github.com/XavierBerger/RPi-Monitor-deb)

The last one would probably be my choice if you don't already have a monitoring solution in place. It is fairly easy to setup and get working on the Pi, allows tracking multiple stats. if IRC it does not have alerts, nor does it keep historical records (but this may be more than you need.

One last option is to ship the data to a third party service that will graph the received data. This may incur a cost and may present a security concern. Observium is just one option in this space, there is even a Pi specific [tutorial](http://youresuchageek.blogspot.com/2013/01/howto-raspberry-pi-monitor-your.html)

This is by no means an exhaustive list, but they are some of the more popular solutions. A quick google search for graph Raspberry Pi CPU or monitor CPU Raspberry PI. Should turn up several more options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do Ctrl-Alt-Del the same way you would on Windows.